# D3js.org banner like image gallery

Tags: d3.js

I want to create an image gallery much like d3js.org has on their home page. Can someone please help? I have tried it but I am finding it difficult to link separate images to links that a in SVG element in that banner. www.d3js.org.

Comment: i am unable to understand how they give images and link them. when i inspected element and saw that they have given "ex.jpg?3f2d00ffdba6ced9c50f02ed42f12f6156368bd2" as image source. this image appears to be a combination of all images behind this SVG. I do not understand what this argument is after image and how are they combining images like this? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, they are definitely using d3.js [Hexagonal Binning](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145).

Then, the individual elements are styled with offsets into this image: http://d3js.org/ex.jpg

Comment: you are right. does this mean that the image is combined before given as a source? if so then can you give me a routine please to combine images much like this. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: the combined image is called a "sprite."  here's a generator: https://draeton.github.io/stitches/